# How can I fix the 'No gradients provided' error when using a custom loss function in Keras?

Tags: keras, loss-function

I have written a custom loss function for my model.
But I get this problem during training.
I searched a lot for the reason, but I couldn't find it.
can you guide me?

```
def myloss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_one = tf.convert_to_tensor(1)
    y_zero = tf.convert_to_tensor(0)
    y_wrong = (K.sign(y_true * y_pred) < 0.0)
    y_final = tf.where(y_wrong, y_one, y_zero)
    return tf.reduce_mean(y_final)
```

raise ValueError(f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(79, 52) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.05606492, -0.05658552, -0.06255285, ..., -0.19837967,
0.03807114,  0.07168372],

I simulated the problem in Jupytor notebook and the output type is tensor

```
y_true=np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9])
y_pred=np.array([0.05,0.1,-0.1,0.1,-0.3,-0.4,1,2,300])
y_true=tf.cast(y_true,dtype='float32')
y_pred=tf.cast(y_pred,dtype='float32')
y_one=tf.convert_to_tensor(1)
y_zero=tf.convert_to_tensor(0)
y_wrong = (K.sign(y_true * y_pred) < 0.0)
y_final=tf.where(y_wrong,y_one,y_zero)
tf.reduce_mean(y_final, axis=0)
```

<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>

Comment: the sign function is not differentiable, you cannot use it in a loss.